# Sort by bar dissapeared in Windows 7 folder explorer when viewing icons

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, icons, sorting

Under Windows 7 sorting by thumbnail icon files takes longer, or a different path of clicks.

I have to switch viewing files in details mode (select from the sorting bar) and then sort by date modified, then get back to the icons view mode.

I don't even bother right-clicking because sort by DATE MODIFIED doesn't exist by default so I have to add it from the menu and then make the sorting. So tiring!  Can't believe they took this bar off. It was priceless!

Is there a shortcut or way to make this sorting (by date modified) quicker?

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you add it (the **Date modified** column) in **Details** view? You only need to do this *once*, and then it will persist. Here's what I suggest:

1. `Right-click the folder / Properties / Customize tab` and select the **folder template** (for example, **General Items**):

   [image: 1]

   You can also select the *Also apply this template to all subfolders* checkbox (purpose should be obvious).
2. Now switch to the **Details** view and add the columns you'd like to sort by (for example, **Date modified**)
3. Then switch to the view you prefer (for example, **Small icons**), `right-click in the folder / Sort by / Date modified`, `right-click / Group by` (if required) etc.
4. Once you have the folder view set up *exactly* how you like it, go to `Organize / Folder and search options / View tab` and click on the `Apply to Folders` button:

   [image: 2]

   Click **Yes** when prompted and this will make ***all*** folders that use the **General Items** template look *exactly the same*. So basically, all you need to do is spend some time to set up a single folder as you like it, and then you can easily replicate the view across all other folders.

Comment: Yeah, but like this I make this view sorting for all folders and I don't mean this.

Comment: So you want to do it only for a few folders and not all, but don't want to add the *Date modified* column in Details view either?

Comment: No, I just want to do it for specific existing folders.

Answer (score 0):

Go to organize > folder and search options > view tab > always show menus. Then under the view menu you can do the sort by and customize this to whatever you want to be able to sort by.

Comment: not what I meant, sorry. This is the long way I already do.